# Centos 7 can't talk to Internet

Tags: linux, networking, ping, centos-7

Newbie trying to install/set up `Centos 7`. Can ping other machines in the domain, but can't ping gateway, google.com etc. Gets `destination host unreachable` for `gateway` and `unknown host google.com` when pinging google.com

Please advice.

`etc/sysconfig/network-scripts:`

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp4s0
iUUID=c39e3407-a566-4586-8fb9-fd4e3bfc4617
DEVICE=enp4s0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR="192.168.192.150"
GATEWAY="208.67.254.41"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
DNS2="8.8.4.4"
```

`etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

`etc/sysconfig/network`

```
# Created by anaconda
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=centos7
GATEWAY=208.67.254.41
```

Comment: Setup the NETMASK and also make sure your GATEWAY is within that subnet, if not make sure you have a route to the GATEWAY.

Comment: @shinjijai Sorry I didnt check here earlier. Yes that was the problem, I was using the ISP gateway ip, updating it to my router ip fixed the issue.